# How are objects stored in an array?

Tags: c++

I think I have a basic problem of understanding instantiating objects from classes or rather storing them in variables / arrays.

I have a class

```
class sensor{
  public:
  // Constructor
  sensor() {
    isObject = true; // Define that an object has been instantiated
  }

  bool isObject = false; // By default set this property to false
};
```

and an array

```
sensor sensorList[5];
```

I thought that the defined array is only reserving as much memory as it is necessary for storing the maximum amount of possible elements (of type `sensor`, so here 5 x 1 Byte for the property `isObject`).

But if I `Serial.println` e.g. `sensorList[1].isObject` I get 1 as result, so the object has already been "instantiated" (= the constructor has obviously been called) without any explicit `sensor sensor1;`. Can someone please explain me why?

Comment: Non-instantiated objects aren’t a thing in C++. If something is an *object*, it’s instantiated. Uninitialised memory has no associated object type and can’t be accessed, except to instantiate objects.

Comment: if you  put something such `std::cout <<"sensor constructor\n";` within sensor ctor you will see it called 5 times

Comment: `sensor sensorList[5]` will default-construct  (i.e. call the constructor that can accept no arguments) each of the five elements of the array.

Comment: @George That’s not true. C++ doesn’t use the terminology “primitive type”, and you can can have class types that aren’t default constructed upon initialisation.

Comment: @KonradRudolph _C++ doesn’t use the terminology “primitive type”_ And neither did I :) George did

Comment: @GianPaolo Ah, I meant to reply to George, Stack Overflow auto-completed the wrong @-name.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: _and you can can have class types that aren’t default constructed upon initialisation._ So there is a possibility prevent the objects to be auto-constructed?

Comment: @alve89 Only for [trivially default-constructible types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivial). .These types behave like `int`. However, it is *still* forbidden to access their memory location before initialisation (and causes undefined behaviour). You can’t do anything useful with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sensor sensorList[5];` is not only reserving memory, it is creating the objects using the default constructor, take the code:

```
int main()
{
    sensor sensorList[5];
    std::cout << sensorList[3].isObject;
    return 0;
}
```

It's almost instinctive to a C++ programmer that this will definitely work, and indeed it does. The objects were constructed using the only one you have in your class, thus the default constructor, so the output will be `1`, `true`, had you not a constructor it would use it's own default constructor, in this case setting the variables to it's value, `isObject` would be `0`, `false`.

Answer (score 2):

When you write:

```
void f() {
    sensor sensorList[5]; // [1]
}
```

The compiler will reserve `sizeof(sensor) * 5` bytes in the stack *and* call five times the default constructor `sensor::sensor()` at line [1], once for each of the objects.

> Can someone please explain me why?

Since it is what you almost always want, the language was designed that way. You can still separate the two steps in C++, but it requires different syntax (placement `new`) which is very rarely used unless you are designing containers, for instance.

The alternative would be to require developers to be always explicit about those two steps, which would increase the lines of code (and therefore bugs too).

Comment: To OP, for reference about placement-new, search for `T* tptr = new(ptr) T;`  in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new

Comment: Actually the separation is what I wanted (mainly because of my misunderstanding) but I can simply add a method to set the variable `isObject` manually to `true`.